# HTACCESS how do i battle with my code to get the right redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

My HTACCESS file currently looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On        
RewriteBase /

# stop directory listings
#Options -Indexes 

#stops htaccess views
#<Files .htaccess>
#order allow,deny
#deny from all
#</Files>        

# redirect game folders     
RewriteRule ^games/([^/]+)/([^/]+) games.php?author=$1&slug=$2 [L]   

# redirect edit     
RewriteRule ^protected/edit-game/([^/]+)/([^/]+) protected/edit-game.php?author=$1&slug=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^admin/edit-game/([^/]+)/([^/]+) admin/edit-game.php?author=$1&slug=$2 [L]

# redirect view     
RewriteRule ^protected/view-game/([^/]+)/([^/]+) protected/view-game.php?author=$1&slug=$2 [L]   

# redirect user
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+) user.php?user=$1 [L]  

# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]     

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]   

ErrorDocument 404 /error-404.php
```

I have a new requirement to make it so when someone goes www.domain.com/im-a-page-in-database

It goes to my page.php, grabs the hidden 'slug' -> 'im-a-page-in-database' and queries the database returning that specific page object.

Thing is, if I add into my HTACCESS file something like this:

```
# redirect pages/posts 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) page.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

It just overwrites all the previous rewrites that may be successful and displays my page.php regardless of where it is placed in the htaccess file?? I thought L meant if the rule was recognised... it should stop trying to do stuff. so if i put my new line under all my redirects, it should do the page check last.. but nope :(

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a way of debugging htaccess files? Like a record of what it has done?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because of your 301-Redirect? The browser caches these redirects, so you'll have to try an other browser or clear your cache.

Comment: hm.. no, doesn't seem to be just a caching issue. Alas, it's hard to 100% tell because i've used all my browsers.. but i have pressed ctrl + F5 extra hard on all the browsers and closed and reopened firefox and iegay.. i mean ie9 *

Comment: does your firefox cleans the cache automatically when being closed? Otherwise try to clean it by yourself

Comment: Damn, nah. just tried again. I am assuming there is something wrong with the code rather than the hope for it being just cache issue. I've just emptied out ie9 and firefox cache completely (and ofcourse chrome is still not working either). Cheers for that though, I have had cache issues before. :(

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this. Okay fine, I have a huge application now that will take some time to re-code but really if there is a better way of doing all the above. Pray tell.

Comment: i am starting to think i might need to re-do alot of this code
instead of redirect pages with lots of htaccess rewrites.
if i redirect all urls to one page (silently)
i could then include specific files based on whatever the url is
it may be better...?

Comment: Actually I would really appreciate if anyone has any better ideas? I'm questioning which way to do this now considering the above htaccess doesn't work.